# The function value is not a number

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use `NSolve` and `NMaxValue` to solve `pn` for a problem like:
$$
     u(x^*,p_n)=0\\
    \text{subject to}\ \  u(x,p_n)\leq u(x^*,p_n) \\
         x\geq0.01
$$

My code is

```
L = 10;
q = 0.09;
Rf = 1.02;
vp[R_] := R^0.88;
vn[R_] := -2.25 (-R)^0.88;
w[P_] := P^0.65/(P^0.65 + (1 - P)^0.65)^(1/0.65);
Px[x_, pn_] := q*CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (R - x*(L/pn - Rf) - 0.075)/0.15] + (1 - q)*CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (R + x*Rf - 0.075)/0.15] ;
```

Run the following code, I got the error message

```
utility[x_?NumericQ,pn_?NumericQ] := -NIntegrate[w[Px[x, pn]]*D[vn[R], R], {R, -Infinity, 0}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"] + NIntegrate[w[1 - Px[x, pn]]*D[vp[R], R], {R, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"];

max0=0.0000879165;
NSolve[NMaxValue[{utility[x, pn], x > 0.001}, x] == max0, pn, Reals]
```

> NMaxValue::nnum: The function value -utility[0.0914736,pn] is not a number at {x} = {0.0914736}.

And use the code below gives a new error message

```
utility2[x_?NumericQ,pn_?NumericQ] := -Integrate[w[Px[x, pn]]*D[vn[R], R], {R, -Infinity, 0}] + Integrate[w[1 - Px[x, pn]]*D[vp[R], R], {R, 0, Infinity}];
Solve[MaxValue[{utility2[x, pn], x > 0.001}, x] == max0, {x,pn}, Reals]
```

and

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value ... is not a number at {pn,x} = {0.918621,1.66352}.

Comment: `utility2` is undefined, although that does not explain the first error message.

Comment: Try `max0 = Rationalize[0.0000879165, 0];
NSolve[NMaxValue[{utility[x, pn], x > 10^-3}, {x}] == max0, pn, Reals]` and note the last error message.  Do the same with `Solve` and you will see the same error message.  Then try `FindRoot`.

Comment: Thank you very much. `FindRoot` do help solve the problem.